# Creating QWidget in a class

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I am trying to create a window in my class.

I went through the documentation : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-widgets-toplevel-example.html

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QWidget window;
window.show();
return a.exec();
```

This does show the window when the code is in main.cpp .

But I want to create the window in other class.
When I use  the line :

```
QWidget window;
window.show();
```

It doesn't give me the window, and the program also doesn't quit.

So how can we create a widget in QT in our own class?

Comment: Your code probably doesn't work because the widget is destroyed at the end of the scope (your function?), so it is deleted right after your show it. You need to lean more about C++ object lifecycle and maybe how Qt handles memory management.

Comment: @xander So if I want to create my widget in the my class and not in the main class then how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a sample `QWidget` that initialized and customized:

```
#include <QWidget>

void FileManager::initializeMyWidget()
{
    QWidget *myWidget= new QWidget();
    myWidget->setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
    myWidget->setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    QIcon iconMyWidget(":/Images/Images/image.png");
    myWidget->setWindowIcon(iconMyWidget);
    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    myWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

Now call function and show the widget:

```
initializeMyWidget();
myWidget->show();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should create a Qframe class .h like this

```
class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Window(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
private:
    QLabel *createLabel(const QString &text);
};
#endif
```

and the .cpp

```
#endif
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(createLabel(tr("LEVEL")), 2, 0);
    setLayout(layout);
    setWindowTitle(tr("Tetrix"));
    resize(50, 370);
}

QLabel *Window::createLabel(const QString &text)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(text);
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignCenter);
    return label;
}
```